# customize layered price filter?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, layered-navigation

How can I customize price filter Magento to be based on associated product prices rather than configurable product prices?

In my category page display configurable product with its options. On this page price filter is working fine

I want to filter not using configure product price but using simple product prices which are added as associated products.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`, search the attribute **price** in code, select then look the **Front end properties** :"`Use In Layered Navigation`" and "`Use In Search Results Layered Navigation`" adjust them as you like.